# Shelving small closets - only 1 stud in each wall

Tags: shelving, closet

I have 2 small pantry/closets, both about 22"x22" with small lips by the opening. I want to install some shelving in these closets, ideally ones that I can easily change the height of as needed. The challenge is that there's only 1 stud in each of the 3 closet walls.

My current thinking is either trying to install those closet systems with vertical tracks, but install a single track on each wall and use 3 short brackets to support each shelf, or give up on the adjustability and just install 3 small wall mounted shelf brackets at every point where I want a shelf.

Any thoughts on the above or alternative suggesting would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider Snaptoggle anchors. Just 1/2" drywall is strong enough for the Snaptoggle anchors (assuming that there are enough drywall anchors).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that you have studs in the corners. If you do then there are a number of possible fixes. One of those is:

- Attach plywood, minimum 1/2" thick, to the studs (corners and/or middle) - supported every couple of feet (vertically) by at least two studs.
- Attach the adjustable shelf-clip tracks to the plywood.

I would trust that much more than I would trust any kind of toggle bolts or other drywall anchors. The problem is this is a pantry, which means canned goods, which are *heavy*. (Which reminds me of a story...)